# How to add static value in existing drop down list using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.i need to add one static value in drop down list which is already there using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
     <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Member Type :</span>
     <select class="form-control"  id="nosofvoucher" ng-model="vouchers" ng-options="v.name for v in listOfMember track by v.value "  ng-change="generateCodeRange('nosofvoucher')">
     </select>
</div>
```

The controller side code is given below.

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/selectMemberType.php",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
            var data={'name':obj.member_name,'value':obj.no_of_members+':'+obj.member_type};
            $scope.listOfMember.push(data);
        })
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
```

and its giving the output like below.

[image]

Here there are 3 set of data is present which is dynamic but i need to add another set of data like below which is static.

```
var data={'name':'New Register User','value':0+':'+0};
```

The above data i need to add with existing drop down data.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to just push your static (hardcoded) data to the array after you loop through the response and push each response.

`function successCallback(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
            var data={'name':obj.member_name,'value':obj.no_of_members+':'+obj.member_type};
            $scope.listOfMember.push(data);
        }
      var data={'name':'New Register User','value':0+':'+0};
      $scope.listOfMember.push(data)`
)

Then again, the better way to do it is to wrap this call in a service and have the service or the controller which is calling the service do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.then(function successCallback(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
        var data={'name':obj.member_name,'value':obj.no_of_members+':'+obj.member_type};
        $scope.listOfMember.push(data);
    });
    var newUser={'name':'New Register User','value':0+':'+0};
    $scope.listOfMember.push(newUser);
},function errorCallback(response) {
});
```